# Command /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/pbxcp failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

While building the application on XCode, i get compilation error 
Command /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/pbxcp failed with exit code 1
Any help in resolving the issue would help.
Thanks,
Subrat

Comment: I only get this error when I'm trying to build a Release, but when I build using the Debug active configuration, it builds just fine.

Comment: The code that I'm having this trouble on is lesson01 from Lazy Foo (http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/index2.php), after having resolved this issue (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/138758/how-to-reference-hello-bmp-inside-my-app/138767#138767). It throws this error when ever I try to build a Release instead of Debug, even before applying that fix.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem ..i have remove some images which is display in red color from my Application and restart this application . its work fine ..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and discovered I had referenced rather than copied an image from a network drive which was no longer available into my project. When I removed the reference and instead copied the image into the project the issue was resolved. Hope this helps